# DataFrame has no Reshape Attribute

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to plot to scatter the graph on the following conditions. But, it failed to give a graph. First, it gave me the error message, X and Y size are not equal. Then, when I tried to reshape the dimensions, which is (Row 13 and Col 4), it gave me another error, no attribute reshape, I need your help.

```py
df.reshape((df.shape[0], df.shape[1], 1))

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color = 'green')
plt.title(' Test_Result vs Salary')
plt.xlabel('test_score')
plt.ylabel('salary')
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you give an example of the data that would be in `X_train` and `y_train`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to plot X_train, y_train into 2D plot, make sure that the number of elements is equal. The first error that you encounter meant that either the dimension of `X_train.shape` and `y_train.shape` are not consistent or the number of element of `len(X_train) != len(y_train)` or `(X_train.shape[0] != (y_train.shape[0])`. 
Besides, if your code is exactly what you posted, I don't see any relevance between `df.reshape((df.shape[0], df.shape[1], 1))` and `plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, color = 'red')`. You need a trick to `reshape` pandas dataframe.